# How to create an indexed circular FIFO buffer with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Im trying to create an indexed circular FIFO (first in first out) buffer for holding the last 90 minutes of a candlestick chart for a set of 15 assets in a pandas dataframe aggregated by minute (i.e. window_size=150) to be displayed in real time on a client side application(candle stick graph). It would maintain the close, open, high, low and volume features respectively for each asset per (1m) time step. Individual candlesticks would be updated by a websocket whereby the latest time interval would be updated per price (candlestick) change. What would be the most efficient mechanism to represent this data structure in pandas,the client side application requires output of the shape [5,15,90] as seen in as_frame representing [close, open, high, low, volume] the 15 assets and the 90 intervals respectively.

thus the data would be represented as such:

```
assets  time   close    open    high    low    volume
asset1  time1  0.001    0.002   0.003   0.001  0.001
        time2  0.001    0.001   0.003   0.001  0.001
        ...
        time90 ...

...

asset15 time1  0.001    0.002   0.003   0.001  0.001
        time2  0.001    0.001   0.003   0.001  0.001
        ...
        time90 ...
```

I have implemented a naive solution with python pandas:

```
class Buffer():
    def __init__(self):
        self.cols = [
                'asset',
                'timestamp',
                'close',
                'high',
                'low'
        ];

        self.lvls = [
            'asset',
            'timestamp'
        ]

        self.frame = pd.DataFrame(
            columns=self.cols
        );

        self.frame.set_index(self.lvls)

    def add(
        self,
        entry
    ):
        ... what would be the most effective
        mechanism to add to the multi indexed
        dataframe given the entry/record 
        {
           "asset":"ASSET",
           "timestamp": 158090000, 
           "close":1.3, 
           "high":1.4, 
           "low":1.2, 
           "open":1.3, 
           "volume":134.5 
        } 
        such that the dataframe timestamp 
        index does not exceed the given 
        window size?

    def as_frame(
        self,
        assets,
        features,
        window_size
    ):
        outframe = self.frame.set_index(self.lvls)
        outframe = outframe.groupby(self.lvls).last()
        outlist = outframe.to_xarray().to_array()
        return outlist
```

How would I most effectively implement the above problem in pandas? provided there does not exist a more optimal/performant solution given another data structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding the data should be as simple as using `append` with a `dict`, filtering the columns for those that are in the target `DataFrame`.

```
self.frame.append({k:v for k, v in entry.items() if k in self.cols})
```

Based on your question I think you want to keep a `DataFrame` which maintains a continuous 150 second window on the incoming data.

To filter the resulting frame, I would calculate the "start" timestamp from the latest added - the time window, and use that to filter the rows, as follows:

```
start_ts = entry['timestamp'] - 150
self.frame = self.frame[ self.frame['ts'] >= start_ts ]
```

Depending on the size of the DataFrame you may get better performance dropping in place:

```
self.frame.drop(self.frame[ self.frame['ts'] < start_ts ].index, inplace=True)
```